# Add one variable to specify which one of several variables that equals a value

Tags: r, tidyverse

*I'm learning R and looking for best practices here...*

## Main question

Given the tibble `my_tibble`:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 3
  chkA  chkB  chkC 
  <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 NA    NA    NA   
2 x     NA    NA   
3 NA    x     NA   
4 x     NA    NA   
5 NA    NA    x
```

I want to create a variable/column `checked` that specifies which of the variables `chkA`, `chkB` or `chkC` that equals `"x"`. For each observation/row, only zero or one of those three variables can equal `"x"`, while the rest of them are `NA`.

I can solve it with this code:

```
my_tibble <- my_tibble %>% mutate(checked = case_when(
  chkA == "x" ~ "A",
  chkB == "x" ~ "B",
  chkC == "x" ~ "C",
  TRUE ~ "(none)"
))
```

, which produces this tibble:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 4
  chkA  chkB  chkC  checked
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>  
1 NA    NA    NA    (none) 
2 x     NA    NA    A      
3 NA    x     NA    B      
4 x     NA    NA    A      
5 NA    NA    x     C
```

However, I assume/hope there could be a more convenient/elegant solution, perhaps a one-liner or something, as I think this is a frequent problem.

## Bonus/follow-up question

For a "cleaner" tibble, I'd probably like to get rid of the chr variables and their `NA`s, by converting to lgl variables. I solved that with this code:

```
my_tibble <- my_tibble %>% mutate(chkA = ifelse(is.na(chkA), FALSE, TRUE))
my_tibble <- my_tibble %>% mutate(chkB = ifelse(is.na(chkB), FALSE, TRUE))
my_tibble <- my_tibble %>% mutate(chkC = ifelse(is.na(chkC), FALSE, TRUE))
```

, creating this tibble:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 3
  chkA  chkB  chkC 
  <lgl> <lgl> <lgl>
1 FALSE FALSE FALSE
2 TRUE  FALSE FALSE
3 FALSE TRUE  FALSE
4 TRUE  FALSE FALSE
5 FALSE FALSE TRUE
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here can use `across` with `mutate` for multiple column.  Also, the output of `is.na` is logical and it can be negated (`!`) to return the opposite instead of using `ifelse` or `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
my_tibble %>%
     select(starts_with('chk')) %>%
     mutate(across(everything(),  ~!is.na(.)))
# A tibble: 5 x 3
#  chkA  chkB  chkC 
#  <lgl> <lgl> <lgl>
#1 FALSE FALSE FALSE
#2 TRUE  FALSE FALSE
#3 FALSE TRUE  FALSE
#4 TRUE  FALSE FALSE
#5 FALSE FALSE TRUE
```

Or without anonymous function call

```
library(purrr)
my_tibble %>%
   select(starts_with('chk')) %>%
   mutate(across(everything(), negate(is.na)))
# A tibble: 5 x 3
#  chkA  chkB  chkC 
#  <lgl> <lgl> <lgl>
#1 FALSE FALSE FALSE
#2 TRUE  FALSE FALSE
#3 FALSE TRUE  FALSE
#4 TRUE  FALSE FALSE
#5 FALSE FALSE TRUE
```

---

For creating the column name based on the occurrence of `NA`, a vectorized option is with `max.col`

```
nm1 <- sub('chk', '', names(my_tibble))[max.col(!is.na(my_tibble), 'first')]
nm1[!rowSums(!is.na(my_tibble))] <- NA_character_
my_tibble$checks <- nm1
my_tibble
# A tibble: 5 x 4
#  chkA  chkB  chkC  checks
#  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> 
#1 <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  
#2 x     <NA>  <NA>  A     
#3 <NA>  x     <NA>  B     
#4 x     <NA>  <NA>  A     
#5 <NA>  <NA>  x     C
```

---

An option in `tidyverse` to create the column would be to first `rename` the columns by removing the 'chk' prefix, then use `imap` to loop over the columns, replace the non-NA elements with column name and use `coalesce` to return the first non-NA value, create the 'checked' column in 'my_tibble'

```
library(stringr)
my_tibble <- my_tibble %>%
   rename_all(~ str_remove(., 'chk')) %>%
   imap_dfc(~  case_when(!is.na(.x) ~  .y)) %>%
   invoke(coalesce, .) %>% 
   mutate(my_tibble, checked = .)
```

-output

```
my_tibble
# A tibble: 5 x 4
#  chkA  chkB  chkC  checked
#  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>  
#1 <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>   
#2 x     <NA>  <NA>  A      
#3 <NA>  x     <NA>  B      
#4 x     <NA>  <NA>  A      
#5 <NA>  <NA>  x     C
```

#### data

```
my_tibble <- structure(list(chkA = c(NA, "x", NA, "x", NA), chkB = c(NA, NA, 
"x", NA, NA), chkC = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, "x")), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1):

One `dplyr` option for finding the column with x could be:

```
df %>%
 rowwise() %>%
 mutate(checked = names(.)[replace(which(c_across(everything()) == "x"), length(.) == 0, NA)])

  chkA  chkB  chkC  checked
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>  
1 <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>   
2 x     <NA>  <NA>  chkA   
3 <NA>  x     <NA>  chkB   
4 x     <NA>  <NA>  chkA   
5 <NA>  <NA>  x     chkC
```